# How can I add a user and add in Active Directory with Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I created a Active Directory with domain local called **ITTFDOM.local** and I created one Organisation Unit with the name **ITSTTF** where I created two groups Marketing and Sales.

My assignment is: Create a user with a password, and add this user in Active Directory and put it in this OU.All this is must be done with **POWERSHELL** ﻿How can I do?

Comment: This is one of the most common things anyone ever does with PowerShell so you can find plenty of examples.  To get help here, paste some specific code you've tried and mention what isn't working and we can help direct you.

Answer (score 0):

```
If (!(Get-Module).Name.Contains("ActiveDirectory")) { Import-Module "ActiveDirectory" }
$OU = "OU=ITSTTF,DC=ITTFDOM,DC=local"
$GivenName = "John"
$Surname = "Doe"
$Name = "Jonh Doe"
$Username = "j.doe"
$Password = "p@ssw0rd"
$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
New-ADUser -Name $Name -GivenName $GivenName -SamAccountName $Username -Path "OU=Managers,DC=enterprise,DC=com" -AccountPassword $SecureString -Enabled $true
```

Please refer to  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-aduser?view=winserver2012r2-ps for more details.